# How to loop X times in Django?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have user reviews on my site. Each review has a rating of 1-5 stars. I want to print that many stars. How do I do it? I only see `{% for X in Y %}` which lets you iterate over a list, but not a certain number of times.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the [Template range filter](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1357/) by [zalun](http://djangosnippets.org/users/zalun/):

```
from django.template import Library

register = Library()

@register.filter
def get_range( value ):
  """
    Filter - returns a list containing range made from given value
    Usage (in template):

    <ul>{% for i in 3|get_range %}
      <li>{{ i }}. Do something</li>
    {% endfor %}</ul>

    Results with the HTML:
    <ul>
      <li>0. Do something</li>
      <li>1. Do something</li>
      <li>2. Do something</li>
    </ul>

    Instead of 3 one may use the variable set in the views
  """
  return range( value )
```

Answer (score 5):

No need for a custom filter - `make_list` will do the job:

```
{% for i in '123'|make_list %}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this *won't* work. That returns `[1,2,3]` *not* `[0,1,2,...,122]`.

Comment: Yes, that's what I intended for it to do - as the OP requested.

Comment: I am the OP, and I'm pretty sure that's not what I requested... how is this looping a "certain number of times" or "X times" given an (integer) rating between 1 and 5?